Github R package and Rcpp Exports
I am trying to understand a package from Github (the package is not available in R cran).
However, I could not find several functions which are actually being called within some other functions in that package!
And if I define a already defined function by any other name, the function doesn't work. For example, say in the package there is a function
oldfunction <- function (nn){m <- nn}

I copied the oldfunction's whole source code, and define it as myfunction <- function (nn){m <- nn}. Here oldfunction works, but myfunction gives me an error.
I can see that there are code files in the authors github link that say they have used Rcpp Exports. The issue is that I am completely a layman here.
Does the Rcpp Exports use functions that are defined in C++ which may not be provided by the authors in their github Rcode files?
I would truly appreciate any suggestion in this regard.

Often packages use internal functions that are not exported, i.e. you can't get them using internal_fun. You need doing package:::internal_fun. For instance, consider contrasts() of the stats package (which is a base package loaded by default), inside there is a .Diag() function.
> contrasts
function (x, contrasts = TRUE, sparse = FALSE) 
{
    [...]
    if (!contrasts) 
        return(.Diag(levels(x), sparse = sparse))
    [...]
}
<bytecode: 0x573380b6c578>
<environment: namespace:stats>

Even though stats namespace is loaded,
> any(grepl('stats', loadedNamespaces()))
[1] TRUE

.Diag can't be found.
> .Diag
Error: object '.Diag' not found

Using `:::` will work:
> stats:::.Diag
function (nms, sparse) 
{
    n <- as.integer(length(nms))
    d <- c(n, n)
    dn <- list(nms, nms)
    if (sparse) {
        if (!suppressPackageStartupMessages(requireNamespace("Matrix"))) 
            stop(gettextf("%s needs package 'Matrix' correctly installed", 
                "contr*(.., sparse=TRUE)"), domain = NA)
        methods::new("ddiMatrix", diag = "U", Dim = d, Dimnames = dn)
    }
    else array(c(rep.int(c(1, numeric(n)), n - 1L), 1), d, dn)
}
<bytecode: 0x57337f73d3b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>

Conclusion
In the copied source code, replace internal_fun with package:::internal_fun to make it work. To avoid having to install the corresponding package, you can also copy the source code of package:::internal_fun (which can sometimes turn out to be a deeply nested endeavor). I did not explain special Rcpp export procedures in the answer, but explained the principle. Basically, you would have to find the corresponding C++ code in the package and proceed in a similar way.

I have followed your instruction. But this is not working. I tried regcell:::threshold_mat and got
{
    .Call(`_regcell_threshold_mat`, xmat, lambdamat, soft)
}
<bytecode: 0x614ec14460f0>
<environment: namespace:regcell>``` Then I tried `regcell:::_regcell_threshold_mat` and got the error `Error: unexpected input in "regcell:::_"`

Again I wrote regcell:::`_regcell_threshold_mat`  , which gives me
[1] "_regcell_threshold_mat"

$address
<pointer: 0x614eba064ba0>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: regcell
Filename:
       /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/regcell/libs/regcell.so
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "CallRoutine"      "NativeSymbolInfo" ```. But this is clearly not a function!

@hht Found cpp functions of that package there.

are these cpp functions in C++ programming? and they are called with .Call?

@hht You could save the code in a regcell.cpp file then run Rcpp::sourceCpp('regcell.cpp') to make functions available.

@hht Usually they're compiled during package installation, think you need doing that by hand.
